# Mac OS X + Rails 3.1 + Unicorn + HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ssl, https, unicorn

Here is my setup:

- Mac OS X 10.6
- Ruby 1.8.7
- Rails 3.1

I have a Rails 3.1 application that starts with Unicorn every time this machine starts up (via a .plist in /Library/LaunchDaemons). The .plist essentially does this:

```
cd /my_application_directory
sudo unicorn -E production -p 80
```

And everything's working fine. However, I'd like to be able to set up SSL so that traffic is encrypted. I don't need a real certificate signed by a real CA, because the application is only accessible over a local network.

I've found articles like [this one](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20041129143420344) on generating certs, but I'm not sure where to go from there (or even if that's the correct starting place).

For my basic needs, I've found the .plist method to be much easier to work with than something like Phusion Passenger, so I'd like to continue doing it that way if possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you show us your plist? need exactly this one

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Unicorn supports being an SSL endpoint, so you're going to need another process to decrypt/encrypt the traffic for you.

On Mac, it's probably easiest to use apache, because it's already installed.

Sorry to not have detailed steps, but you're looking to do the following:

1. Change the port unicorn listens on, to prevent conflicts with apache.
2. Set up Apache to serve SSL, just like your linked reference.
3. Also set up apache to proxy requests to be handled by Unicorn, on the new port you setup. This involves the ProxyPass (and possibly ProxyPassReverse) directive.
4. Configure apache to start when the Mac boots.

Comment: It's been supported on Unicorn since 2011, but is undocumented. See [this](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/mongrel-unicorn/2011-September/001179.html)